# In R how do I shift a time series dataframe forward by 8 hours?

Tags: r, lubridate

Hi I have a df like this:

```
Timestamp            | Price  |
2019-04-30T11:00:00  |  5150  |
2019-04-30T12:00:00  |  5185  |
2019-04-30T13:00:00  |  5212  |
2019-04-30T14:00:00  |  5211  |
```

where `typeof(df$Timestamp)` returns `"character"`

How do I shift the Timestamp forward by 8 hrs? Expected result:

```
Timestamp            | Price  |
2019-04-30T19:00:00  |  5150  |
2019-04-30T20:00:00  |  5185  |
2019-04-30T21:00:00  |  5212  |
2019-04-30T22:00:00  |  5211  |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to datetime class and add the `hours`

```
library(lubridate)
df1$Timestamp <- ymd_hms(df1$Timestamp) +  hours(8)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Timestamp = c("2019-04-30T11:00:00", "2019-04-30T12:00:00", 
"2019-04-30T13:00:00", "2019-04-30T14:00:00"), Price = c(5150L, 
5185L, 5212L, 5211L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```